# how to show port numbers that are listening for the incoming connections under TCPv4?

Tags: linux, command-line, netstat

I want to use command line to show only the port numbers after ":" only

This is what I'm trying to do

```
sudo netstat -ant |grep LISTEN|grep :|sort -n|cut -c 45-
```

It shouldn't list any tcp6 info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed:

```
sudo netstat -4tln | sed '1d;2d;s/[^:]*:\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

this is better:

```
sudo netstat -4tlpen |sed -n '3,$p'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'|cut -f1 -d' '|sort -n|uniq
```

Comment: there is an extra space line with your commnad. But is still a good reference!

Answer (score 0):

Using the basic `grep`, `tr`, `cut` :

```
netstat -4tln | grep LISTEN | tr -s " " ":" | cut -d ":" -f5 | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer at "[Why are IPv4 TCP connections showing as tcp6?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237731/why-are-ipv4-tcp-connections-showing-as-tcp6)" , netstat entries with tcp6 *can* be for IPv4, as tcp6 sockets might be created as AF_INET6 which support both IPv6 *and* IPv4